# Unable to receive/send response from a Promise in Lambda function

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, async-await, promise

I am having a Lambda function, in which I am taking a parameter from Query String and using it to call a downstream service that will inturn return a promise. I am unable to send back the response received by the Promise.

This is my Lambda function:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
     let sessionId = event.queryStringParameters.sessionId;
     const testClient = new Client.WebStoreClient(config);
     const sessionResponse = getSession(testClient, sessionId);
     sessionResponse.then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
     });
     const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(sessionResponse),
     };
     return response;
};

async function getSession(testClient, sessionId) {
     let data = await testClient.getSession(sessionId, headers)
          .then((response) => response.body);
     return data;
}
```

When I am executing this, I am getting a null response: `{ statusCode: 200, body: '{}' }` from the Lambda function output. I tried to console log the value that I have gotten and was receiving this: `Promise { <pending> }`
I am suspecting this to be a Javascript/Typescript Promise issue which I am slightly neglecting. Any help is appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `getSession` function should return Promise in order to consume the Promise in the next line `sessionResponse.then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `response`, you are trying to stringify the promise instead of the promise value and it gives you an empty object as a String.

You can try it:

```
JSON.stringify(Promise.resolve(1)) // output is "{}"
```

You can only access the value of a Promise from inside the callback you pass to `then`.

Think of it this way: inside of `then` is the future, the surrounding code is the present. You can't reference future data in the present.

You probably wanted to write

```
return sessionResponse.then(function (result) {
   return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result),
   }
});
```

The above returns a promise containing your response.

You could have also just written `getSession` this way

```
function getSession(testClient, sessionId) {
     return testClient.getSession(sessionId, headers)
          .then((response) => response.body);
}
```

I suggest that you practice using promises without async/await

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It made me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to geoffrey's answer, note that both of your functions are `async`, meaning you can use the same `await` keyword you used in `getSession()`.

```js
export const handler = async (event) => {
     // ...
     const sessionResponse = await getSession(testClient, sessionId);
     //                        ^
     console.log(sessionResponse);
     const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(sessionResponse),
     };
     return response;
};

async function getSession(testClient, sessionId) {
     let data = await testClient.getSession(sessionId, headers)
          .then((response) => response.body);
     return data;
}
```

This is roughly the equivalent of...

```js
export const handler = (event) => {
     // ...
     return getSession(testClient, sessionId).then((data) => {
           console.log(data);
           const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(sessionResponse),
           };
           return response;
     });
};

function getSession(testClient, sessionId) {
     return testClient
                 .getSession(sessionId, headers)
                 .then((response) => response.body);
}
```

Note that your `getSession()` function is returning a Promise by virtue of `async` (and in the translated example above). Your `handler()` function is likewise returning a Promise, so whatever is calling it will need to use a `.then()` or be `async` itself to leverage an `await`. As you can see this asynchronous requirement cascades.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your approach. I appreciate your time in explaining me where I am making mistakes.